# Bernoulli shift is a measure-preserving transformation

Tags: measure-theory

Let (for simplicity) $(\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N},\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be a Bernoulli scheme, when $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated from the cylinder sets, $\mu$ is $(0.5,0.5)^\mathbb{N}$, and $T$ is "right shift", which means $\forall(x_n)_n\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}: T((x_n)_n)=(x_{n+1})_n$

$T$ is a measure-preserving transformation, but why?

To prove that $T$ is measurable, let $A\in\mathcal{B}$, $T^{-1}(A)=\{x_n\mid (x_{n+1})_n\in A, x_1=0$ or $1\}$.

Is this set measurable? If it is, why $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation? I am struggling to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The set is measurable. This link may be useful: math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960718.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a cylinder set, then $T^{-1}(A)$ is also a cylinder set.  Define $\mathcal{G}$ by
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{G} = \{A \subseteq \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \, \mid \, T^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B} \}.
\end{equation*}
An exercise shows that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Since it contains the cylinder sets, $\mathcal{G} \supseteq \mathcal{B}$.  That is, if $A \in \mathcal{B}$, then $T^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}$, so $T$ is measurable.

If $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a cylinder set, then $\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$ follows by a direct computation.  The family of all cylinder sets if a $\pi$-system (since the intersection of two cylinders is a cylinder) and the family $\Lambda = \{A \in \mathcal{B} \, \mid \, \mu(A) = \mu(T^{-1}(A))\}$ is a $\lambda$-system.  Therefore, Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem implies that $\Lambda \supseteq \mathcal{B}$.  In particular, $\mu(A) = \mu(T^{-1}(A))$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$, so $T$ is measure-preserving.

Comment: May I ask why if $A$ is a cylinder set then $T^{-1}(A)$ is also a cylinder set? Thank you!

Comment: If $A = \{x_{i_{1}} = a_{i_{1}},\dots,x_{i_{N}} = a_{i_{N}}\}$ for some vector $(a_{i_{1}},\dots,a_{i_{N}}) \in \{0,1\}^{N}$ and $i_{1},\dots,i_{N} \in \mathbb{N}$, then $T^{-1}(A) = \{x_{i_{1} + 1} = a_{i_{1}},\dots,x_{i_{N} + 1} = a_{i_{N}}\}$.  (It's a good exercise to check this carefully.)